# TFS 2010 basic - how can I list all code files associated with a work item?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-2010

I have TFS 2010 basic and I would like to view all checked in files that have been associated with a work item.  Any ideas?

Cheers
Tigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the list of changesets associated with the work item, and then the file list associated with each changeset. There is no direct link from work item to changed files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Richard, I'm new to TFS (VSS convert) so i can follow your suggestion up to the point where i can identify the changeset. But what do i do then to view the files related to the changeset?

Comment: Richard, I spotted the All Links tab, which lists the changeset and from there i can double click the changeset to get a list of files.  Cheers Tigger